# Class weights in caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, unbalanced-classes, caret

I'm using the R package *caret* to generate classifiers using a variety of different models on an imbalanced dataset. To overcome the class imbalance problem, I am using the "weights" parameter in the "train" function. This seems to work for some models, but not for others. If I set the weights equal, the rpart classifier, for example, predicts 20% class 1 and 80% class 2, which is very close to my observed class proportions. Setting the weights to 10 and 1, the classifier now predicts class 1 in over 90% of examples, and only 10% class 2.

However, when using the svmLinear, svmRadial, or rf algorithms, the weights parameter has no effect. No matter what class weights I input, the classifiers invariably label 20% as class 1 and 80% as class 2. Looking into the code a little more, it doesn't appear that the "weights" parameter from the "train" function ever gets passed through to the call to the *ksvm* package, which is what *caret* uses for SVM training.

[This link](https://geekoverdose.wordpress.com/2014/07/25/svm-classification-example-with-performance-measures-using-r-caret/) has an example using the svmLinear method in *caret*, and changing the weight vector does absolutely nothing.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Is there any way to determine which models actually accept class weights as an input?

Comment: If its just svm that gives you headaches you could also try the package e1071. The weighting works as in the docs: Edit: Damn, cant format correctly in comments. See the last example in ?svm.

Comment: Now caret supports svm weights by kernlab  https://github.com/topepo/caret/commit/50558f0da1ac2b79a319c1c5046c6c1dbc472054

Comment: For `caret`, to find out which models accept class weights, can go to [github.com/topepo/caret/](https://github.com/topepo/caret), search keywords: `if(!is.null(wts)) theDots$weights <- wts`. At this moment, 32 pieces of modelInfo return, which means there are 32 built-in caret models available to pass class weights.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't gotten around to implementing it for all the models that can accept weights. Right now, it should work for `rpart` variants, `glmnet`, `gamSpline`, `glmboost`, `gamboost`, `evtree`, `ctree`, `ctree2`, `chaid`, `cforest`, `blackboost`, `treebag`, `glm`, `glmStepAIC`, and `bayesglm`.

Note that `ksvm` *function* does not have a weight parameter, so those models won't be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's great to hear directly from the source. I'm a little confused about your last sentence, I don't really know what you mean by a model being "enabled". I'm using the "class.weights" parameter, although I just noticed that the linked example I posted tries to use a parameter just called "weights", which I suppose doesn't exist.

Comment: kernlab has weight parameter now and caret supports that.  Please consider updating this answer.  I was mislead at first.

Comment: Almost two years passed.Is there an updated version of this list? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps check here: https://topepo.github.io/caret/available-models.html#  There is a column that allows you to see what models have "weight" for a tuning parameter.